# format-patch for a single file

Tags: git

I have a file called test_module.c that has some differences that I want to apply to my local working copy.

I tried to create patch file from the remote by doing the following. However, git didn't complain about any errors. And didn't create any patch file either.

```
git format-patch master/dev_branch test/test_module.c
```

It is possible to create a patch of a single file, that I can apply?

(Using git version 1.7.5.4)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you give `git format-patch` a single revision, it will produce patches for each commit *since* that revision.  If you see no output from that command, then I suspect that there were no changes to that file between `origin/master` and your current `HEAD`.  As an alternative, you can provide a revision range (e.g. `origin/master~3..origin/master`) which covers the changes introduced to that file.  Or, if the changes you want to produce a patch for are just contained in the single commit at the tip of `origin/master`, you can use the `-1` parameter, as in:

```
git format-patch -1 origin/master test/test_module.c
```

Comment: I used the following with the hash being the last commit. 
git format-patch [hash] origin/master test/test_module.c
However, I got these errors. What would normally cause these?
error: patch failed: test/test_module.c:176
error: test/test_module.c: patch does not apply
Thanks.

Comment: I think you may want `git format-patch [hash]..origin/master test_module.c` instead, or `origin/master` may be regarded as a path.

Comment: Any idea where this is documented? The official man page doesn't seem to say anything about being to specify a file (though it does work): https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch.

Comment: Note the `-1` parameter (which says “give me the changes from this commit, as opposed to everything since this commit”) works with a hash, not just the tip of the branch. I.e. you can do `git format-patch -1 abc1234 path/to/file`.

Comment: @OhadSchneider The `-1` option is documented in the `git-format-patch` manual: *-<n> Prepare patches from the topmost <n> commits.*

Answer (score 20):

You can use following syntax for creating patch for single file:

```
git format-patch [commit_hash] [file]
```

Comment: it actually works!  the shown sha1 is incorrect, but it did get me the correct patch that I wanted.

Comment: Use tow dashes: `git format-patch [commit_hash] -- [file]`