# Git add code from old commit

Tags: git, merge

How to merge old commit code into HEAD? If I want to merge the complete file of test.js at commit hash `e123ee12` in to HEAD test.js.

I try to using cherry-pick but if there are many commit before I need to cherry-pick one by one.

I also try to checkout to the `e123ee12` and add a empty line then commit and checkout back to master and merge the commit.But it will only merge the line that I add,will not merge all line to the master.

How to merge all file at old commit into master?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset or revert a specific file to a specific revision using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)

Comment: It's different.

Comment: @ChienLee: How is that duplicate different? I see exactly the same question...

Comment: The possible duplicate question is about revert and reset,but this is about pick old commit and merge into current commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and generate a [patch from that old commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658352/6309) (including for [a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885229/6309))

```
 git format-patch -1 <sha> -- aFile
```

Then apply it to your current HEAD

```
  git am -3 < file.patch
```

Note: for multiple commits, you can [cherry-pick a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309).

Comment: why it `format-patch -1`  then `git am -3` not `git am -1`

Comment: @ChienLee the -3 if for doing a merge three-way and has nothing to do with the -1 (patch on one commit only): `-<n>`: Prepare patches from the topmost `<n>` commits.

Comment: I was doing the following

`git format-patch -1 e123ee12`
then it generate `0001-<commit>.patch` then `git checkout master`
then `git am -3 0001-<commit>.patch`

Comment: I create another test git folder and it works but still not work for the original project(no line change after apply),still try to figure out.

Comment: @ChienLee OK. Maybe it considers the history of that file in the original project and thinks that patch was *already* applied...

Comment: Do you know how to avoid it to consider the history.

Comment: @ChienLee not sure. May be with a shallow clone?

Comment: try to `git clone --depth <till the commit depth> `and do `am` again but still get `Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.`